# Any new info about solar flares hitting the Moon added by the LADEE mission?

Tags: the-moon, solar-flare, dust

[This article](http://www.nasa.gov/topics/solarsystem/features/dream-cme.html) from 2011 mentions simulations about the sputtering effect caused by a solar flare hitting the Moon:

> "We found that when this massive cloud of plasma strikes the moon, it
>   acts like a sandblaster and easily removes volatile material from the
>   surface," said William Farrell, DREAM team lead at NASA Goddard. "The
>   model predicts 100 to 200 tons of lunar material – the equivalent of
>   10 dump truck loads – could be stripped off the lunar surface during
>   the typical 2-day passage of a CME."

The researchers said they were waiting for [LADEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Atmosphere_and_Dust_Environment_Explorer) to confirm these simulations and add new data, but I didn't find any conclusions on this subject on the [mission website](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LADEE/news/index.html). I was interested if this event can create a significant static electricity difference between the 2 sides of the Moon, causing some sort of lightnings on the edges or even a mini-version of a dust storm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd probably be most interested in the results of the Lunar Dust EXperiment (LDEX).  A [2015 paper](http://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/leag2015/pdf/2083.pdf) states

> LDEX data show no evidence for an electrostaticallylofted
>   dust component at densities greater than a few
>   per m3

I am assuming the solar flare stuff didn't pan out, otherwise it would be mentioned in the various [LDEX summary papers](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/06/150617135035.htm).  In addition, the NASA DREAM group site doesn't seem to have anything relevant LADEE results, and they're the ones that brought the subject up in the first place.